# Main Screen looks like shifts after splash screen disappear in iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, splash-screen

I added splash screen for iPhone 5 Retina 4" in info.plist. The view after the splash screen has same background image as of splash screen. But When I launch application it looks like first view background image is shifting down. I tried all cases hiding status bar and unhiding  it also tried hide status bar at launch time but nothing is working for me. Any one has any idea.

Comment: actually the launch image height for iPhone 5 is 1136 where as you are  taking the view size 548 that is 20 pixel small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background position to `-statusbar.height` (e.g: -20), so that it matches the position of the splash.

If you want to hide the status bar, you also need to set `[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];` in your view controller, otherwise the space for the status bar may remain unoccupied.

Comment: Thats work like charm for me Thanks a lot... :) This is the fasted ever answer got from you guys ....:)